# jQuery 3.0 deferred don't execute then callback when called resolve

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred, jquery-3

I'm trying to make my library work in jQuery 3.0 and it don't work because of breaking changes in Deferred objects, I have code like this:

```
    function ready(defer) {
        return function(fun) {
            if (defer.state() !== 'resolved') {
                defer.then(fun).fail(function(e) {
                    self.error(e);
                });
            } else {
                fun.call(fun);
            }
        };
    }
```

and I have two methods pause and resume

```
        pause: function(visible) {
            if (self.id() == 4) {
                console.log('pause call');
            }
            cmd_ready(function ready() {
                onPause();
                paused = true;
                if (self.id() == 4) {
                    console.log('pause', paused);
                }
                command_line.disable();
                if (!visible) {
                    command_line.hidden();
                }
                if ($.isFunction(settings.onPause)) {
                    settings.onPause.call(self);
                }
            });
            return self;
        },
        resume: function() {
            if (self.id() == 4) {
                console.log('resume call');
            }
            cmd_ready(function ready() {
                paused = false;
                if (self.id() == 4) {
                    console.log('resume', paused);
                }
                if (terminals.front() === self) {
                    command_line.enable();
                } else {
                    if (self.id() == 4) {
                        console.log('not front');
                    }
                }
                command_line.visible();
                var original = delayed_commands;
                delayed_commands = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < original.length; ++i) {
                    self.exec.apply(self, original[i]);
                }
                self.trigger('resume');
                var fn = resume_callbacks.shift();
                if (fn) {
                    fn();
                }
                scroll_to_bottom();
                if ($.isFunction(settings.onResume)) {
                    settings.onResume.call(self);
                }
            });
            return self;
        },
```

The deferred is needed because I'm executing pause before command_line object is created.

and I call resolve after first pause:

```
        if (self.id() == 4) {
            console.log('resolve');
        }
        command_defer.resolve();
```

and the order of logs like this:

```
pause call
resolve
resume call
resume false
resume call
resume false
pause true
```

the order should look like this:

```
pause call
resolve
pause true
resume call
resume false
resume call
resume false
```

why pause then callback is called long after resolve is called? it was working in jQuery 2.

Comment: That `ready` method is a horrible thing to do. It should be `return defer.then(fun);`, no branching on anything.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @Bergi I wanted to have the code that will be called synchronously like without the deferred object.

Comment: Yes, I can see that you wanted that, and it's exactly [what you should not do](http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony)

Comment: When you have added how you are calling this code, please also show the expected result not just the actual one.

Comment: Ok, this one is resolved the `resolve();` callback don't call then synchronously. it's breaking change in jQuery 3.0 Deferred objects.

Comment: @Bergi the promise is only for case when someone call pause before command_line object is created on initialization, it actually should be synchronous. The user code would look weird if it need to call then after each method.

Comment: Yes, that's a breaking change, but it was a deficiency of jQuery and never a good design to rely on synchronous callbacks.

Comment: You might want to use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/ directly

Comment: This is a horrible scheme.  You're using a piece of promises and then trying to reinvent a whole bunch of other functionality that already exists in promises and, in the process, are making things about 10x more complicated than they need to be.